# Custom Picklist field of the custom object values that have hierarchy levels

Tags: picklist, hierarchy

I want to implement the following idea:

Account has a custom picklist field where you can select the related territory (another custom object that has name and parent territory) for it. Territory has hierarchy levels. For example, country, region, city, street etc.

Please advise how can it be realized.

And if I want after selecting, for example, country from the picklist, also to select region, then city and street, should I use a **Visualforce page** or can it be realized in SalesForce directly? Also an account can have multiple territories (several regions in one country, several countries) for it.

Comment: How many levels are your looking to use for your dependency fields?

Comment: At least 3 levels (country - region - city)

Comment: So these records will be in the Territory__c object? So you will have one entry Territory and three fields? Country, Region, and City?... is that the initial idea?

Comment: Territory__c has only Name and lookup field to other parent Territory__c object.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, based on your initial idea I think that this can be easily achieved by using picklist and field dependencies. If either of those picklists is more than 300 entries you should be good to go.

> 1. Create a picklist named: 'Country' and add all the countries you need, remember, no more than 300.
> 2. Create the second picklist name:'Region', here you need to add you regions but you can't go above 300 entries.
> 3. Create last picklist, name: 'City', here you are your cities, no more than 300.
> 4. From the Account object, you can select 'Field Dependencies', click that button and select the 'Country' picklist on top, bellow
>      select 'Region'. Save that and get back to 'Field Dependencies', this
>      time in top select 'Region' and bellow select 'City'.
> 5. You have created a relation between those fields or more SFDC speaking, a dependency.
> 6. If you click on 'Field Dependencies' now you can see those dependencies and you can click edit for each of them. If you do so, now, you can select what options will be available for each option that is part of your picklist.

This is the easiest way to accomplish this with out of the box functionalities. If your values are not too many you can use this. 
Now, if you think that you will go above 300 entries you need to probably look for some other solution that probably will need some coding. There are also some Apps that can help you with this but the probably will cost money.

So, let me know if this helps, somehow :)

Regards.

Comment: Thank you, Viasur. But if I have only Territory__c object with fields name and lookup on parent Territory__c and I want to connect Account to the territory then should I add all hierarchy fields (country, region, city) to the account or can it be somehow realized with lookup to one Territory__c object? And if I want dependency on the previous picklist. For example, after selecting country, in the next picklist there are only regions available for the selected before country. Please advise how can it be implemented.

Comment: Hello Alex, it really depends on what you want and how you can use your data. If you want to use the Territory__c object you can create a lookup relationship to the Account object and create new Territory__c records from the account, but you need to populate the rest of the fields on the Territory__c record, (country, region, city). You can also create Territoty__c records with their country, region, and city values and add them to the Account. My idea was to have a set of values defined in the dependencies fields because I think is the simplest way to accomplish this.